Issue with TwinCAT3 and Factory IO simulation
Working on a project that I'm using TwinCAT3 and Factory IO through Modbus TCP/IP and it works perfect. But today I got an warning in Twin CAT that says;
'TCOM Server' (10): Mailbox Full '10500': cnt:574533 sender:350 target:10500 res:0             Build
My target is local.
Anyone knows how to solve this?
Tried to find information in Infosys, google, restart program but no help so far.
